# Bootstrap 3 - offsets within fluid containers

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have two offset divs (col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3) within two separate fluid containers.  For some reason, the width of the first is slightly narrower than the second.  I want to match the width of the first with that of the second.  Can someone help?  Be gracious, I'm a newbie.  The page is at http://prayerlb.com/prayerLB/index1.html.

Here's the pertinent HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div id="bluebar_top"></div>
        <div class="city_bg">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3">
              <div id="top"><a href="index.html"><img src="images/lbpb_header.gif" class="img-responsive" alt="Long Beach Prayer Breakfast"></a> 
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">

  <!-- BOOTSTRAP 3.3.6 NAVBAR CONTENT -->

  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container-fluid" style="margin-top: -20px">
  <section class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3">
      <div class="row"><img src="images/photo_banner2.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Strength in Community..."></div>
        <div class="row main_article">

      <!-- MAIN CONTENT -->

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

...and the CSS:

```
#bluebar_top {
height: 20px;
width: 100%;
background-color: #02425f;
}
.city_bg {
background-image:url(../images/lbpb_header1.jpg);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size: contain;
background-size: cover;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: inspect the element in your browser development tools and because of some margins/padding it may seem that the offsets are not equidistant but they are.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have nested columns and rows.  Meaning that you have columns and rows inside of columns and rows.  If you are not going to contain a floated column meaning something like `.col-md-7` then you dont need to add rows and columns.  And if you put them inside of each other then it will add extra padding.

So the markup for your top section really should probably look something like the following:

```
<div id="bluebar_top"></div>
<div class="container-fluid city_bg">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3">
      <a id="top" href="index.html"><img src="http://prayerlb.com/prayerLB/images/lbpb_header.gif" /></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can remove the `#bluebar_top` from the container and just put it on the top of the page and then add your `.city_bg` class to the container itself.  Then you can put your row and column inside the container and you don't need to nest them inside of other rows and columns.

Hopefully that makes a little bit of sense.  There are more examples of this throughout your page and that is more than likely why if you look at the bottom of your page you have a horizontal scrollbar that shouldn't be there.  This is happening because extra padding and negative margins are being added from the nested columns and rows.

I have made a fiddle of how I would have written your page below.  Check it out and see how the markup differs.

Note:I used .col-sm-offset instead of .col-lg-offset in the demo just so you can see it easier in the fiddle so you will need to resize output window to the .sm size to see the difference instead of .lg size just for easier viewing.

[Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/wamosjk/pvbhy6fj/)

Anyway hopefully this all helps out and if you have any questions feel free to comment below

Comment: Thank you very much.  I finally implemented this and it works beautifully!

Comment: Hi, again.  I would like to add a breakpoint perhaps at about 1200px to have the layout pop out to about 90%, then perhaps scale down to the next break at 650px.  I'm very open to suggestion, but the display just gets too narrow between those two markers.This is my first responsive project, so I'm learning as I go.  The existing offsets, and the plethora of media queries already present in bootstrap makes it difficult to know where to begin.  I appreciate any advice you can offer.  Thanks!  (http://prayerlb.com)

Comment: Instead of using .col offsets you may want to consider removing them and just changing .container-fluid to just .container.  The .container class has a max-width at certain breakpoints so you wont neeed to have the offset column to contain your content you can just use .container.  Then it will be at full width at mobile sizes also.  Like the following example https://jsfiddle.net/wamosjk/8f3q6u50/ .  Let me know if this is what you are looking for if not we can come up with a different solution.

Comment: Adding to my above comment I have added a meda query to the .container class to have a max width of a percentage at 1000px.  You can change this to 1200px I just used 1000px in the fiddle so you could see it better when you resize the fiddle.  But just in case you wanted more space at bigger screens you can add this media query that i put on the bottom of css sheet in the fiddle.  Try it with this media query and without and if you dont want the extra space at larger screens you can just do without it.  Also if this answered your question consider checking this as answered above.

Comment: Thank you. I tweaked the code at jsfiddle.net/wamosjk/8f3q6u50, and the results are at http://prayerlb.com/index1.html. My changes are as follows:

1) I wanted the city_bg image to extend to the full width of the screen, so I enclosed the <div class="container"> and the <div class="row"> containing lbpb_header.gif inside a <div class="container-fluid city_bg">.

2) When I adjusted your media query, and experimented with some of my own, the navbar shifted to two rows as I scaled down, so I changed the container class in the nav to container-fluid.

Comment: Instead of adding the .container-fluid to the city_bg just use .city_by because then you will have the same problem as in your original question you will have nested containers and your content will not line up so there is no reason to add the .container-fluid to this class.  Also it may be better practice to use just width in the media query for the container instead of max width, thats my bad I was in a hurry it probably wouldnt matter but its just better.  I edited the fiddle take a look at it again.  I also added another query for mobile screens to take a look at.

Comment: Here are the MQs that seem to get the results I want. Please advise if you see any caveats.  Thanks!